# how to send crypto data token id in the request header

Tags: apex, api, crypto

i am making a request to a endpoint in apex. i have encrypted data and key using crypto class, now i want to send the encrypted data and token id in the request header for authorization using GET method. the below code is not working and no data is getting pulled from the endpoint api.

> (note: api using basic authorization is working fine.)

below is my code.

```
public static string encryptMessage(String message, String secretKey){
        Blob key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(secretKey);
        Blob data = Blob.valueOf(message);
        Blob encrypted = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, data);
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encrypted);
    }

    String secretKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==';
    String tokenId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
    Datetime d = System.now();
    String payload = 'd='+d.format('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSZ')+';c='+10+';t='+10;
    String message = tokenId + ':' + encryptMessage(payload, secretKey);

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('my endpoint url');
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8'); 
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth' +     EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueOf( message)));

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
string response = res.getBody();
```

Comment: What does the response look like? responseCode, header and body

Answer (score 0):

If you are following Oauth then in Oauth 2 we do something like this.

```
string authorizationHeader = 'Bearer '+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueOf( message));
req.setheader('Authorization',authorizationHeader);
```

So you might need to change your code.

Comment: i tired, its not working

Comment: @RitzArlekar are you getting any error? if yes then post that. Also which authentication protocol you are using Oauth 2 or Basic?

Comment: i am unaware of the authentication protocol to be used for 'AES128' encryption. that is what i want to know. but certainly not using Basic.

Comment: @RitzArlekar you can confirm that from the documentation of site i which you are making request. SF support oauth2.0